# Checking continuity of Rational vs irrational functions

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Suppose we have a function $F$ defined by: 
$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
          0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational, and} \\
          1/n & \text{if $x = m/n \in \mathbb{Q}$, where $m/n$ is irreducible $m,n>0$.}
\end{cases}$$

I have a feeling that this function is discontinuous everywhere but my exam paper solution states that it is continuous at every irrational number.

I racked my brains but still didn't see **how** this could be true at all. 
Please someone try to show how this can be true. Any hint will do.

Comment: I have seen the other posts regarding similar type of questions but the answer didn't suffice.  Please do help me

Comment: You claim that you have seen other similar questions.  Please add context to your question by providing links to those questions in the body of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: think about an irrational number like $\sqrt{2}$. $F(x)$ is $0$ for irrational $x$ near $\sqrt{2}$ and is small for rational $x$ near $\sqrt{2}$ (because a good approximation $m/n$ to $\sqrt{2}$ will have $n$ large, so that $1/n$ will be small). So $F(x)$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thanks I got it now perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given  $\epsilon > 0$, what $x$ are there with $f(x) > \epsilon$?  Show that if $y$ is irrational, there is some $\delta > 0$ so that all of these are at distance more than $\delta$ from $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q.$

For $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ let $S_n=\{a/b: a\in \Bbb Z\land n\ge b\in \Bbb Z^+\}.$ Note we do not require $a,b$ to be co-prime in the def'n of $S_n.$

(1). We show that for each $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ there exists $\delta_n>0$ such that $S_n\cap (-\delta_n+x,\delta_n+x)=\emptyset.$

(2). We use (1) to show that $F$ is continuous at $x,$ as follows: Given $\epsilon>0,$ take $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ large enough that $1/n<\epsilon.$ Then take $\delta_n$ as in (1).

Now if $y\in  (-\delta_n+x,\delta_n+x)\cap \Bbb Q$ then $y\not \in S_n,$ so if $y=a/b$ with $a\in \Bbb Z$ and $b\in \Bbb Z^+$ and $\gcd (a,b)=1$ then $b>n$... (otherwise $y=a/b \in S_n$)... so $|F(y)-F(x)|=F(y)=1/b<1/n<\epsilon.$

And if $y\in (-\delta_n+x,\delta_n+x)$ \ $\Bbb Q$ then (obviously) $|F(y)-F(x)|=0<\epsilon.$

Therefore $$\delta_n>0\land \forall y\, (\,|y-x|<\delta_n\implies |F(y)-F(x)|<\epsilon).$$

(1*). There are many ways to prove (1). Let $T_n=\{a/(n!):a\in \Bbb Z\}.$  Since $x\not \in \Bbb Q$ there exists $a_n\in \Bbb Z$ with $a_n/(n!)<x<(1+a_n)/(n!).$ So let $\delta_n=\min (x-a_n/(n!),\,(1+a_n)/(n!)-x\,).$ Since $S_n\subseteq T_n,$ we have $y\in S_n\implies y\in T_n\implies |y-x|\ge \delta_n.$ Note  we do not need a "good" estimate for $\inf \{|y-x|: y\in S_n\}$; we merely need that it is not $0.$

Comment: We can also show that if $s,s'\in S_n$ and $s\ne s'$ then $|s-s'|\ge 1/n^2,$ and from this we can show that $\inf \{|y-r|: y\in S_n\}>0$ for any $r\in \Bbb R$ \ $ S.$

Comment: A corollary to (1) is that if $(a_j/b_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence of rationals converging to an irrational $x,$ with $a_j , b_j\in \Bbb Z,$ then $|b_j|\to \infty$ as $j\to \infty.$